# Command in Github Action unexpected output

Tags: grep, find, github

I'm trying to compile all my C projects within an Action on GitHub.

This is the command I'm running:

```bash
\! find . -name Makefile -type f -execdir make re \; 2>&1 | grep -qF 'Error 1'
```

It exits 1 if `grep` finds 'Error 1', which is what `make` displays when it fails. Locally it works fine, and I've even pulled a fresh branch to make sure it wasn't some local changes which caused a biased result. But nothing...

This is what is displayed in my pipeline (raw log on Github):

```
2023-02-21T13:45:13.6257013Z ##[group]Run \! find . -name Makefile -type f -execdir make re \; 2>&1 | grep -qF 'Error 1'
2023-02-21T13:45:13.6257510Z [36;1m\! find . -name Makefile -type f -execdir make re \; 2>&1 | grep -qF 'Error 1'[0m
2023-02-21T13:45:13.6313689Z shell: /usr/bin/bash -e {0}
2023-02-21T13:45:13.6313965Z ##[endgroup]
2023-02-21T13:45:13.6506466Z ##[error]Process completed with exit code 1.
```

I've also tried putting the script into a `build.sh` file, but I get a `grep: conflicting matchers specified` warning, and no error (even if `make` error is forced)

Tests I've performed:

- Raw script ([action link](https://github.com/herbievine/42/actions/runs/4233290990/jobs/7354056473) | [workflow link](https://github.com/herbievine/42/blob/3242be99542e581c237aef87a7a21e76975cca6d/.github/workflows/lint.yaml)) => Exits 1 for no reason
- Script in file ([action link](https://github.com/herbievine/42/actions/runs/4233457414/jobs/7354447655) | [script link](https://github.com/herbievine/42/blob/447e76194718c467f8146e07443a762c1b9d4669/.github/workflows/lint.yaml)) => Exits 0 for no reason + grep warning
- Script in file (forced error) ([actions link](https://github.com/herbievine/42/actions/runs/4233459589/jobs/7354452594) | [script link](https://github.com/herbievine/42/blob/447e76194718c467f8146e07443a762c1b9d4669/.github/workflows/lint.yaml)) => Exits 0 for no reason + grep warning

---

If there's a better alternative to the command I'm using, which compiles all Makefiles in immediate subdirectories, that would be great too! :)